# What is an active record?

Tags: activerecord

What exactly is an active record?  I hear this term used in Ruby post and nhibernate.

Answer (score 8):

***[Active record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)*** was initially a ***[design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science))*** which involved wrapping database table operations in a class.

In a Rails context, however, it is also the proper name of a ***[particular software component](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/vendor/rails/activerecord/README.html)*** which implements the design pattern in Ruby for ***[object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)***, and the name of its associated ***[module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html)***.

Answer (score 2):

Active record is a design pattern where you map each table to a class. This means that each object created from this class represents a row in the table.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Answer (score 1):

It s a Design Pattern.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html